# Google Drive web API not working

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

My problem is I am not able to do folder level search in google drive through my third party application. When we search inside a folder, I want items from the current folder and subfolders.
But when i am searching, I am getting results only from the current folder being searched, that is results from subfolders is not fetching.
Given below is the api I am using,

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folderid

please reply as early as possible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive folders are not folders.

"Parent Folders" are actually simple properties of a file, eg. a file can have multiple parents.

If you want to descend into subfolders, you'll need to do it yourself, or have your app make all of its files children of a common folder (remembering that children can have multiple parents. If you do it yourself, resist the urge to recurse - it's slow, expensive and error prone.

See [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive/41741521#41741521)

Comment: Is there any single API to search subfolders? Because, when we use this API, https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files, I am getting the complete files/folders from the drve.

Comment: The search features have not changed between v2 and v3.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive/41741521#41741521

Comment: Many thanks @pinoyyid. I acheived it through recursive method, at metadata level, so performance also not a problem.