# how to upload a file in googleDrive non-root folders using APIs?

Tags: google-drive-api

I can upload files in root folder of Google-drive using Google-drive APIs. But I cannot upload files to non-root folders. Is it possible to upload a file in non-root folders using APIs?and DO we have any other APIs for uploading a file in non-root folders.

I am using "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files" Url and I am trying to append file-Id to this Url, but I failed to upload the file to a sub-folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest start by reading this post [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive). Even though the question is about searching, you will find the answer will help you to understand Drive folders. Once you realise that a Folder is really just a label, the answer will be obvious.

In simple terms, your file metadata must contain an array called "parents" (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations). Simply populate that array with the file IDs of the folders you want the new file to be created in.

Comment: "{    "title" : "<File-Name>",  "mimeType" : "<Content-Type>",  "parents": [{"id": <File-ID>}]  }" I put this in request body and its working, Thank you.