# List All Folders and their files in Google Drive SDK

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive SDK to get a list of my files and display them on my site!
I am using a service account for server-side integration!

I have like 4-5 folders in my root directory and 50-60 files in each of them!
What **scopes** should I use and what **method** should I use so as to retrieve all the folders and then their sub files?

I cant seem to find documentation for getting folders or so! In v2 it was by using **childrens** method but PHP SDK is on v3.

My flow would be like this.

Authenticate using service acccount->get list of folders->get list of files inside this folder->display them.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you understand that a **Service Account is not your personal Google account**. So unless you share all your folders, you will not be able to access **your** files by authenticating using a Service Account. See [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)

Once you are authenticating using the correct credentials. The best approach is to:-

1. Authenticate using your own credentials
2. List all of your folders `files.list q='mimetype=application/vnd.google-apps.folder and trashed=false`
3. For those folder ids you wish to see the children `files.list q=parents in (id1, id2,...) and trashed = false`

See [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive) for some background on how folders work.