# How to detect orphan files?

Tags: google-drive-api

Suppose I have the following folder structure in `MyDrive`:

```
     (A)
FolderA\FolderB
FolderC
```

I give permission to the user *email@gmail.com* to `FolderA` and `FolderC`. 
When I give permission to the user *email@gmail.com* to `FolderA` it will be also cascaded to `FolderB` by Google design. The user *email@gmail.com* will see only `FolderA` and `FolderC` in his **Shared with me** folder. He will see `FolderB` when he'll go inside `FolderA`. The user sees in his **Shared with me** folder the following folders structure:

```
FolderA
FolderC
```

Now, if I remove *email@gmail.com* from `FolderB` and then share `FolderB` again with *email@gmail.com* he will now see in his **Shared with me** the following folders structure:

```
   (B)
FolderA
FolderB
FolderC
```

How I can detect those orphans like `FolderB` with Google Drive SDK?

Comment: What do you mean by "orphan like FolderB"?

Comment: At first the user saw in his root folder `Shared with me` just `FolderA` and `FolderC`. After my changes he sees now `FolderA`, `FolderC` and `FolderC` in his root folder `Shared with me`. So, for me `FolderB` is orphan since he should see this folder only inside `FolderA`. So, I want somehow to be able to check if a user sees `FolderB` along with `FolderA` and `FolderC` or only inside `FolderA`.

Comment: @pinoyyid, I've updated my post to describe what folders the user sees at each step.

Comment: Sure. I understand what the user sees, and to me it seems as expected. You are saying folderB is an orphan, but in what way? Have a look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive, and focus on "in Google Drive, Folders are not folders!".

Comment: To answer the question, "how do I detect stuff like folderB", fetch its meta data and have a look at what's in its parents array. There may or may not be a clue there, but essentially you are asking for the history of how folderB ended up in that state and I suspect the only way is to go back through its revisions.

Comment: I looked at its parents array. It's always `FolderA`, so it doesn't help me to detect stuff like `folderB`. If google drive shows folders in the structure like in my case it means that it does have TWO parents - "FolderA" and "NULL" or something that telling google drive that it should show it in root folder "Shared with me". How do I get this information.

Comment: try the "shared" and "permissions" properties. If there's nothing significant in there then I'm out of suggestions.  What is your use case for needing this information?

Comment: 1 - I know how to get "permissions", but how do I get "shared"?
2 - How does google drive know to show `FolderB` along with `FolderA` and `FolderC`?

Comment: shared is a boolean property of the file/folder. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files

Comment: What about my second question? Regarding the "shared", how the boolean will help me?

Comment: my last thought on this is get the meta data of folderB at point A (see my edit to your question) using files.get:fields=* and then do it again at point B. Then compare the two sets of meta data. Either there is a difference you can use or there isn't.

Comment: @pinoyyid, but how does the google drive itself distinguish these two cases? It's obviously it can distinguish between them otherwise I wouldn't see `FolderB`.

Comment: @pinoyyid, can you please tell me how does the google drive itself distinguish these two cases then?