# Getting Google drive subfolders

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

How can I get the subfolders of a drive folder?

The v2 `service.Children.List(folderId)` method seems to have disappeared.

I'm using the c# Drive.v3 api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet

```
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
```

This will list all files. To list files within a given folder id (ie. its children), refer to https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1ListRequest.html and add

```
        listRequest.Q = "'my_folder_id' in parents";
```

Comment: I later found out about the query parameter--and was unimaginably relieved.

Comment: What about listing the subfolders and files within this parent folderID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive