# Download google drive folder

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, drive

How can I download a folder, using the client api?

I know I could:

1. Recursively traverse and download children.
2. Download the entire drive file-tree, match children of the folder I wish to download, before then downloading the files.

In the web-app, you can download folders as a ZIP, is this feature only allowed within the browser, or is there a way to access this within a desktop app?

What is the best option for downloading a folder?

Comment: There is no API equivalent to the web-app, 'download folder as zip' feature

Comment: Then, what is the best thing to do--that was my Q?

Comment: You'll need to traverse/descend your folder using files.list and download the files individually. Remember that Google files can't be downloaded, only exported into a specified format. So all of this logic you will need to write yourself.

Comment: There are some hints here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive

Comment: I'll opt for my original recursive idea.

Comment: but how you do the recursive job?