# How to get google drive folders path

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have authenticated for google drive using passport js

Now I have access token

So I am looking for to get all folders path with their respective folder Id.

I am not aware what parameters need to set to get only folders path and folder id

I am using [google-drive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-drive) library for fetching lists

Here is my code

```
var googleDrive = require('google-drive')
 var param={}
 googleDrive(accessToken).files().list(params, (err, response, body) => {
                       //fetch folders path
                    })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

`var param={}`

to

`var param={q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}`

With all due respect to the authors of the library you are using, be very careful. Either a library deal with **all** of Drive's subtleties (eg. following nextPageTokens) or it will cause you problems. The Drive REST API is a very well formed API, and you could just as easily access it using Fetch, which, being Promise based, makes for much cleaner code and allows you to use `async await`.

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid. This is working fine. but it is not showing full path for a folder

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. Folders in Google Drive don't really have paths. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive