# Search files recursively using google drive rest

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to grab all the files created under a parent directory. The parent directory has a lot of sub directories followed by files in those directories.

```
parent
--- sub folder1
    --- file1
    --- file2
```

Currently I am grabbing all the ids of sub folders and constructing a query such as *q: 'subfolder1id' in parents or 'subfolder2id' in parents* to find the list of files. Then I issue these in batches. If I have 100 folders, I issue 10 search queries for a batch size of 10.

Is there a better way of querying the files using google drive rest api that will get me all the files with one query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive) to your question.

Same idea from your scenario:

> ```
> folderA____ folderA1____folderA1a
>        \____folderA2____folderA2a
>                     \___folderA2b
> ```

There 3 alternative answers that I think you can get an idea from.

> **Alternative 1. Recursion**
>
> The temptation would be to list the children of folderA, for any
>   children that are folders, recursively list their children, rinse,
>   repeat. In a very small number of cases, this might be the best
>   approach, but for most, it has the following problems:-
>
> - It is woefully time consuming to do a server round trip for each sub folder. This does of course depend on the size of your tree, so if
>     you can guarantee that your tree size is small, it could be OK.
>
> **Alternative 2. The common parent**
>
> This works best if all of the files are being created by your app (ie.
>   you are using drive.file scope). As well as the folder hierarchy
>   above, create a dummy parent folder called say "MyAppCommonParent". As
>   you create each file as a child of its particular Folder, you also
>   make it a child of MyAppCommonParent. This becomes a lot more
>   intuitive if you remember to think of Folders as labels. You can now
>   easily retrieve all descdendants by simply querying `MyAppCommonParent
>   in parents`.
>
> **Alternative 3. Folders first**
>
> Start by getting all folders. Yep, all of them. Once you have them all
>   in memory, you can crawl through their parents properties and build
>   your tree structure and list of Folder IDs. You can then do a single
>   `files.list?q='folderA' in parents or 'folderA1' in parents or
>   'folderA1a' in parents....` Using this technique you can get
>   everything in two http calls.
>
> Alternative 2 is the most effificient, but only works if you have
>   control of file creation. Alternative 3 is generally more efficient
>   than Alternative 1, but there may be certain small tree sizes where 1
>   is best.

Comment: I think Alternative 3 is what I am doing but Alternative 2 is a great solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is really handy. Thanks.

Comment: Google is now enforcing single parent in Google Drive, so Alternative 2 would not work anymore.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-single-parent

Comment: For the alternative 3, is there a limit on number of parents we can specify?

Answer (score 2):

```py
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('your JSON credentials' % path, scope)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

folder_tree = "NAME OF THE FOLDER YOU WANT TO START YOUR SEARCH"
folder_ids = {}
folder_ids['NAME OF THE FOLDER YOU WANT TO START YOUR SEARCH'] = folder_id

def check_for_subfolders(folder_id):
    new_sub_patterns = {}
    folders = service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and parents in '"+folder_id+"' and trashed = false",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",pageSize=400).execute()
    all_folders = folders.get('files', [])
    all_files = check_for_files(folder_id)
    n_files = len(all_files)
    n_folders = len(all_folders)
    old_folder_tree = folder_tree
    if n_folders != 0:
        for i,folder in enumerate(all_folders):
            folder_name =  folder['name']
            subfolder_pattern = old_folder_tree + '/'+ folder_name
            new_pattern = subfolder_pattern
            new_sub_patterns[subfolder_pattern] = folder['id']
            print('New Pattern:', new_pattern)
            all_files = check_for_files(folder['id'])
            n_files =len(all_files)
            new_folder_tree = new_pattern 
            if n_files != 0:
                for file in all_files:
                    file_name = file['name']
                    new_file_tree_pattern = subfolder_pattern + "/" + file_name
                    new_sub_patterns[new_file_tree_pattern] = file['id']
                    print("Files added :", file_name)
            else:
                print('No Files Found')
    else:
        all_files = check_for_files(folder_id)
        n_files = len(all_files)
        if n_files != 0:
            for file in all_files:
                file_name = file['name']
                subfolders[folder_tree + '/'+file_name] = file['id']
                new_file_tree_pattern = subfolder_pattern + "/" + file_name
                new_sub_patterns[new_file_tree_pattern] = file['id']
                print("Files added :", file_name)
    return new_sub_patterns 

def check_for_files(folder_id):
    other_files = service.files().list(q="mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and parents in '"+folder_id+"' and trashed = false",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",pageSize=400).execute()
    all_other_files = other_files.get('files', [])   
    return all_other_files
def get_folder_tree(folder_id):
    global folder_tree
    sub_folders = check_for_subfolders(folder_id)

    for i,sub_folder_id in enumerate(sub_folders.values()):
        folder_tree = list(sub_folders.keys() )[i]
        print('Current Folder Tree : ', folder_tree)
        folder_ids.update(sub_folders)
        print('****************************************Recursive Search Begins**********************************************')
        try:
            get_folder_tree(sub_folder_id)
        except:
            print('---------------------------------No furtherance----------------------------------------------')
    return folder_ids 

folder_ids = get_folder_tree(folder_id)
```

Comment: define folder_tree = "name of your root folder "
for example ,
if you are inputting folder_id of folder 'The folder' , define folder_tree = "The folder" outside the  function 'get_folder_tree'.