# Getting files from specific folder using Drive Api (PHP)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a folder in my google drive and I want to list its **files** and **subfolders** using google drive Api through a search box. Does Api provide any flexibility to get folders.

I've a script to get folders but it's not working properly. Showing some trashed folder. I want files too.

```
   $this->client = $googl->client();
   $this->drive = $googl->drive($this->client);
   $folderId = '0B4JDg65OBlTM3RseUk';
   $parameters = [
            'q' => "'$folderId' in parents",
            'fields' => 'files(id, name, modifiedTime, iconLink, 
             webViewLink, webContentLink)'];
   $result = $this->drive->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

Comment: What exactly isn't 'working properly'? Does it run? Does it crash? Does it produce errors, and if so what error? It's hard for people to help you if you don't describe WHAT is going wrong.

Comment: Well it's showing some folders that are in trashed. But I want to list all the files in folder.

Answer (score 0):

To list files, you may use the [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method of the API. This method accepts the `q` parameter, which is a search query combining one or more search terms.

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "incompleteSearch": boolean,
  "files": [
    files Resource
  ]
}
```

Example for `files.list`:

> Search for the ID `1234567` in the `parents` collection. This finds all files and folders located directly in the folder whose ID is `1234567`.

```
'1234567' in parents
```

To see the valid search parameters, you may visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters).

Comment: and how is this going to take folderid and give response as it childs

Comment: If you would click the second link, it will lead you to the page where you can see the valid `q` parameters and some examples. I have edited my answer to include the example for searching files and folders located in the specified folder ID.

Comment: if there are sub folders than how I'm supposed to get the files from subfolder ?

Comment: Please refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545336/search-files-recursively-using-google-drive-rest/46562607#46562607).