# Fetching the path of the file decreases my API performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, backend

I have implemented a function to fetch the drive files and display their path of the file in the drive. I take a file's parents field and hit the file API again to fetch the name of the parent folder name. If the folder has a parent again, then I call the same function again and so I made it recursive. I have a common array to populate the file paths name. So, If I can now process only one file at a time. If I try to process many files at a time since the array to populate path of a file is declared globally, the parallel process doesn't populate my file with appropriate results. Looking for a better approach.

```
let labels = [];
getDriveItems: ({params}) => {
    // hit API to fetch all files
    //for each file call get path
    if (nextPageToken) {
        getDriveItems({params})
    }
}

getpath(fileDetails) {
    if (fileDetails.parents) {
        parentFileDetails = {get file details in parentFileDetails}
        labels.push(parentFileDetails.title);
        if (parentFileDetails.parents.length > 0) {
            getpath(parentFileDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is too unspecific. Actual API calls aren't shown, it's unclear how it can be improved and what 'decreases my API performance' actually means. The code is currently synchronous. Of course, it blocks main thread if there's a considerable amount of recursive calls.

Comment: @estus. Well, I am looking for a solution to resolve that block!

Comment: see option 3 of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive

Comment: @pinoyyid that's cool. But In my scenario, I store only files and not the folders

Comment: Again, *it's unclear how it can be improved and what 'decreases my API performance' actually mean*. Please, provide all relevant details that describe that 'my scenario'. Specific code-related problems need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  . Otherwise the question is considered off-topic and can be closed.

Comment: A simple thought.. use batch requests. If you already are, you should actually provide call details in your question.

Comment: do not use batch requests. They achieve nothing and massively complicate your code.

Comment: @KøusikaGanesh You have misunderstood option 3 of that answer. You should fetch *all* of the folders in a single API call. Then create an in-memory tree of your folder structure onto which you can then map your files.

Comment: @pinoyyid so you say I need to preserve all details I fetch during the call to fetch all drive items...and then map through the preserved data ... Instead of hitting another time!!! Could you please let me know whether I'm correct?

Comment: fetch all folders, not all items

Comment: Will try it @pinoyyid