# Google Drive APi - Get path of file by id

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the path of file or folder by its ID.

I know that parents are just like tags but with Google Drive on the pc it's not the case: they are always folder and file in its hierarchical structure.

So I try this code:

```
function getPath( fileId ) {

    path = ""
    names = [];

    while ( id != '0AN9ZF6qdu2FUUk9PVA' ){ //the right string is the root id

        get_metadata( id )
            .then( function(response){
                    if( response.result.parents )
                        names.push( response.result.name )

                    id = response.result.parents[0];
            })
    }

    path = names.reverse.join('/');

    return path;
}
```

It doesn't work. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for it not working is that you have failed to deal with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. Your statements will execute something like:-

```
get_metadata
get_metadata
get_metadata
get_metadata
get_metadata
get_metadata
get_metadata
get_metadata
names.push
get_metadata
get_metadata
names.push
```

Secondly, your function param is `fileId` but this is never used in the function body. Instead you are using `id`.

It's worth looking at option 3 of [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive) which means you can do what you are trying to do in a single GDrive API call.

So, with the best will in the world, you have a lot of JavaScript learning you need to do.

Comment: I always used Promise in efficient way (i.e. Dropbox API), but the new deal here is about convert a file id to a full path. Nevermind the variables id and fileId, I mismatch that variables just when I wrote the comment. I think if your link is valid I can resolve my issue in two hours or less. Thanks.

Comment: No, your link doesn't help me. Probably you didn't understand my question. I get the id ( AZ45wefds2561651113213 ) of a file and I want retrieve the full path : "Public/Photos/AnotherFolderName/theFIleWithThatID".

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Unfortunately I think you will fail.

Comment: @PierpaoloFernandez it will be much simpler for you if you can reduce the number of async calls. The linked option 3 means you use 1 request to get folders & their parent folders, and 1 request to figure out which folder is the parent of the file you're searching. then voila, you have everything in memory and your promise resolution code can ignore nesting promises.

Comment: I resolved by me, first with the recursive function, then with the option 3 that actually is the best solution. Thanks.