# List all files in a Google Drive folder and sub folder recursively via the REST API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Is there a way through the Google Drive API to list all the files in a specific folder and its sub folders with out traversing the folder tree and making requests for each folder?

The [File:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list) and [Children](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/get) methods of the REST API only appear to return the files of a specific folder as far as I can tell. Essentially I want the do equivalent of `dir /s` in windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no APIs for retrieving all files including all sub folders in a specific folder. So it is required to do it at the script side. I think that this thread is helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41741520