# Google Drive API v3: service.files().list not returning all folders

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm implementing a tree-based viewer based on the contents of our Google Team Drive file; in order to do this, I'm following the advice given here: [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive), i.e. do 2 API calls - one to get all the folders, and the other to get all the files that are immediate children of those folders.

However, I've noticed that the call to get all the folders aren't returning all of them:

```
res = service.files().list(
corpora='teamDrive',
pageSize=1000,
supportsTeamDrives=True,
includeTeamDriveItems=True,
teamDriveId=TEAM_DRIVE_ID,
fields='files(id,parents,name,mimeType)',
q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"
).execute()

len(res['files'])
# 460
```

Here, the files shouldn't be exceeding the `pageSize`, but I'm definitely missing a noticeable amount of folders from this result, e.g. a particular one with an id of `specified_id`:

```
len([x for x in res['files'] if x['id'] == specified_id])
# 0
```

I don't think it's a permissions issue, as I can fetch this file normally:

```
specific_file = service.files().get(
    fileId=specified_id,
    supportsTeamDrives=True,
).execute()

specific_file

{'id': '...',
 'kind': 'drive#file',
 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
 'name': '...',
 'teamDriveId': '...'}
```

Any other tips on other things to try in order to achieve the goal of getting all the folders in a Google (Team) Drive in one API request would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. Your code assumes that if you have (say) 500 folders, that by giving a `pageSize=1000` that all 500 folders will be included in a single list.execute. **That is not how Drive works.**

The pageSize is only a maximum, so **at most** 1000 folders will be included. The API does not guarantee that all folders up to 1000 will be included. You need to iterate on the `list.execute` include `pageToken` in your request, until `nextPageToken==null`.

Comment: Ooh that's a good shout - I'll accept this answer as soon as I confirm that this fix works!

Comment: Just tried it out now (adding `nextPageToken` to the query and looping the req until it's not returned anymore) and I'm able to construct the tree structure flawlessly - thanks!

Comment: Thank you, been looking all over on how to solve this one.