# how to get the list of all files with a certain extension in all subfolders in a folder in google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api

with this query:

```
"name contains '.extension' and 'folderId' in parents"
```

I get the immediate children with the extension "`.extension`" in the folder with the `folderId`.

How can I retrieve all files with this extension in this folder and all its subfolders?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly retrieving all subfolders in a folder using Google APIs. So it is required to prepare a script for achieving it. For this, I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41741520/7108653) might be useful.

Comment: As @Tanaike said, there is no direct way of doing this, but there can be a recursive function that achieve this. Please, share your code so we all can get a look at it and help you to fulfill your request.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can manage:)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your approach and was able to retrieve all the files with a particular extension from google drive API. I have developed the part of my code using python.

The Query I have used:

```
q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and name contains '.extension' and trashed = false"
```

Also, I have used other field parameters while searching such as

```
kind,incompleteSearch,files/size,files/id,files/name
```

In python; the code will look something like the below:

```
extension_files = self.service.files().list(
                q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and \
                        name contains '.extension' and trashed = false",
                fields='kind,incompleteSearch,files/size,files/id,files/name'
            ).execute()
```

Where service you have to set up by the Google drive access token using the build() and credentials.

Hope this will help you in solving your problem.