# Google Sheets Script Exceeded maximum execution time, even with flush option?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am a noob in coding but managed to adjust the code a bit to do what I need it to do and that is to list the files inside a folder and its subfolder files.

The issue is that the files total is about 50k or more and keeps increasing each day XD
so now most of the time I get a "Exceeded maximum execution time" and sometimes's I don't. Inside the script, there is a flush function so it should reset the timer if I am correct?

I run the script every day I do not know what to do to fix this?
I think the best would be to have a function that will check if it is already listed and if not updated to skip it to speed up the script but again I just do not know atm ware to start.

If someone could help me to fix the " Exceeded maximum execution time" I would be extremely grateful.

this is the script:

```js
function ListarTodo() {
  /* Adapted from Code written by @Andres Duarte in this link:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045664/how-to-list-also-files-inside-subfolders-in-google-drive/63182864#63182864
  */


// List all files and sub-folders in a single folder on Google Drive
  // declare the folder name
  var foldername = 'Beelden';

  // declare this sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // clear any existing contents
  sheet.clear();
  // append a header row
  sheet.appendRow(["Folder","Name", "Last Updated", "Size MB", "URL"]);

    // getFoldersByName = Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive that have the given name.
  // folders is a "Folder Iterator" but there is only one unique folder name called, so it has only one value (next)

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var foldersnext = folders.next();
  var lintotal = 2;

 // Initiate recursive function
  lintotal = SubCarpetas(foldersnext, foldername, lintotal);  
}

function SubCarpetas(folder, path, cantlineas) {
  cantlineas = ListarArchivos(folder, path, cantlineas);
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var mysubfolders = subfolders.next();
    var mysubfolderName = mysubfolders.getName(); 
    var newpath = "";
    newpath = path + "/" + mysubfolderName;
    cantlineas = SubCarpetas(mysubfolders, newpath, cantlineas);
  }
  return(cantlineas) 
}
// list files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
function ListarArchivos(mifoldersnext, mipath, milintotal) {
  var datos = []; //temporary array that we are going to use to record on the sheet
  var files = []; //array with all the files that we find in the folder that we are evaluating
  var file = []; //array that we use to dump the data of each file before saving it
  var total = 0;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var myfiles = mifoldersnext.getFiles();

// We create an array with the data of each file and save the total number of files
while (myfiles.hasNext()) {
    files.push(myfiles.next());
    total++;
}
// we sort the array by file names alphabetically // sorts the files array by file names alphabetically
files = files.sort(function(a, b){
   var aName = a.getName().toUpperCase();
   var bName = b.getName().toUpperCase();
   return aName.localeCompare(bName);
});

////
var vuelta = 0;
var bulk = 500; // We define the number of lines to record each time, in the GoogleDoc spreadsheet
var linea = milintotal; // we define in which line we are going to save in the spreadsheet
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // we go through the array of files and format the information we need for our spreadsheet
    file = files[i];
    var fname = file.getName(); //file name
    var fdate = file.getLastUpdated(); // date and time last modified
    var fsize = file.getSize()/1024/1024; // file size, we pass it from byte to Kbyte and then to Mb
    fsize = +fsize.toFixed(2); // we format it to two decimal places
    var furl = file.getUrl(); //File URL
    datos[vuelta] = [mipath+" ("+total+")", fname, fdate, fsize, furl]; // we put everything inside a temporary array
    vuelta++;
    if (vuelta == bulk) {// when it reaches the defined quantity, save this array with 10 lines and empty it
      linea = milintotal;
//      Logger.log("linea = "+linea); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("vuelta = "+vuelta); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("total = "+total); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("lintotal = "+milintotal); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("registros en datos = "+datos.length); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("data = "+datos); //DEBUG
      sheet.getRange(linea, 1, bulk,5).setValues(datos); // we save the data of the temporary array in the sheet
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // we force the data to appear on the sheet - without this the data does not appear until finished (it generates a lot of impatience)
      milintotal = milintotal + vuelta;
      datos = []; // empty the temporary array
      vuelta = 0;
      }
    }

if (datos.length>0) {// When exiting the loop we record what is left in the data array
      linea = milintotal;
//      Logger.log("linea = "+linea); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("vuelta = "+vuelta); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("total = "+total); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("lintotal = "+milintotal); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("records in data = "+ data.length); //DEBUG
//      Logger.log("data = "+datos); //DEBUG
      sheet.getRange(linea, 1, datos.length,5).setValues(datos);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //ansiolítico
      milintotal = milintotal + datos.length;
      datos = [];
      vuelta = 0;
    }
return (milintotal)
}
```

Thank you all

UPDATE!

So after looking at multiple forumes i found that the best thing atm i can do is make a break for this script by using the following script:

```js
function runMe() {
  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
  
  //do some work here
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
  for(var ii = startRow; ii <= size; ii++) {
    var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", ii);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("runMe")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime+REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
               .create();
      break;
    } else {
      doSomeWork();
    }
  }
  
  //do some more work here
  
}
```

But after trying I do not understand where to divide this to make it work T-T any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> ***I think the best would be to have a function that will check if it is already listed and if not updated to skip it to speed up the script but again I just do not know atm ware to start.***

These links from the official documentation should help:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFolders(String)

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms

You can use the information in the documentation to create a script that only pulls the most recently added and/or updated files.

However, if you need to process a large volume of recently updated files you'll need to leverage some kind of batch processing solution that spans multiple sessions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my question and giving the links. will check them out and see if i can make heads or tails out of it XD. i