# How to extend the sorting to subfolders/all children in Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), I try to sort the folders order by *modified time* (on the green folder).

I use Rest API V3. For my ListRequest I pass the parameters like this:

```
OrderBy = "folder,modifiedTime desc,name"
q       = 'green-folder' in parents
```

[image]

This query ignores other children (red-folders), so it only organizes by the first child folders (blue-folders).
What should I modify on the query?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the subfolders in a specific folder cannot be directly retrieved using Drive API. In your case, it is required to prepare a script for retrieving the subfolders in a specific folder. For example, I think that this thread will be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41741520)

Comment: Which language are you using? You need to use a recursive function on each sub-folder in order to be able to get all the sub-folders.

Comment: Thank you guys! I use C# langugage, but in my case I can’t use recursive solution because of many data and I’m willing to keep uploading some additional data in the future.
Maybe I should use an own database for store the modified folders.