# Google Drive API Search for folders

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of folders so that I can do a search for files within all subfolders. I am using this post (alternative 3) as a reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741521/1485815

My query is like this (I have tried mimetype and mimeType in the query)

```
    $optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 1000
        ,'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink,mimeType,parents, kind, trashed, owners, modifiedTime)'
        ,'q' => "mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
       );                

    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->GoogleClient);
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

I am authenticated fine, but this query gives an error with the following details

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the folder list from the Google Drive using googleapis with PHP.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.
- You want to know the reason of your issue of `Invalid Value`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
,'q' => "mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
```

To:

```
,'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

or

```
,'q' => 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"'
```

- Please enclose the value of mimeType by `'` and `"`.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

Comment: @StripyTiger Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi - I wonder if you wouldn't mind checking this question - I cannot seem to query multiple folders with my query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313289/google-api-query-files-in-multiple-folders-with-php Thank you