# Google Drive API v2: End of life?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there an end of life date for Google Drive API v2? I use v3 for most of my modules, but need the v2.children() function to do one thing. Didn't know if I need to plan to have it deprecated.

Comment: I've seen nothing to warn of any deprecation. What is it you use Children for?

Comment: I was originally using children in order to construct a path to a given file, but after testing, I've come to realize, it is quicker to search all files rather than specify a hierarchy of parent folders in order to get to a file.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive/63321665#63321665

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of this answer, there is no indications that Drive API v2 will be deprecated. Please check [its documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk) for further information.