# Why this script not getting all the folders in google drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made this script to list all subfolders of a given folder, so later I can look up values in another worsheet. But  the script is not picking up all the folders. Why's that

```
function ListaPasta() {
  
  var foldername= 'Main folder name';
  var folderlisting = 'folders';
  
  var mainfolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername).next();
  var folders = mainfolder.getFolders();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['Nome'] );
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var nome = folder.getName();
    sheet.appendRow([nome]);
   
    
  };
}
```

Edit:
I don't want the subfolders of the folders inside the main folder, so I don't need recursion.

The script is not listing all folders and I'm sure of it, because when I look for some folder in the listing (via LOOK functions and using the filter) I can't find it, but if I search in the drive I find it inside the main folder(not as a subfolder of other folders).

Now since the time I posted this question I noticed that when I opened some folders looking for a file it would show the folder as empty, but if I searched for the file name it would find it. After I opened the file and closed it, and then went to the folder and opened it the file would be there. Could be a similar behaviour causing the script to not find some folders?

Not sure if relevant, but the main folder is part of a shared drive.

Comment: You need to use recursion

Comment: the code works for me. So either you want something else or you don't know what the code does. Essentially, you generate a new spreadsheet file named `folders` where you put all the data there. If you expect to get the data to a bound spreadsheet then you should replace: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);` with `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`

Comment: Do you want to list just immediate children, or all descendants of a folder? If it's the former, your code should work; if it's the latter, I think the answer provided by Tanaike will be useful to you.

Comment: I don't need recursion, I don't want subfolders. I just want to list the folders of the main folder. But I know for sure that is not listing some folders, because i've looked for a folder in the list given by the script and the folder wasn't there, but if I got the main folder it is theere.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the folder names of all subfolders in the specific folder using Google Apps Script.
- You want to put the retrieved folder names to Google Spreadsheet.

  - From your script, you want to put each folder name to each row of the 1st tab of the created new Spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the folders in the specific folder are retrieved. In this case using [`getFolders()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolders), only the folders just under the specific folder are retrieved. I think that this is the reason of your issue. When you want to retrieve all subfolders in the specific folder, as one of several methods [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41741520), how about recursively traverse all subfolders using the recursive function?
- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function ListaPasta() {
  const foldername= 'Main folder name';  // Please set the folder name of the specific folder.
  const folderlisting = 'folders';  // Please set the Spreadsheet name.


  // 1. Retrieve the folder names including all subfolders.
  const getAllSubfolders = (f, folders = [foldername]) => {
    const fols = f.getFolders();
    const temp = [];
    while (fols.hasNext()) {
      const fol = fols.next();
      temp.push({name: fol.getName(), folder: fol});
    }
    if (temp.length > 0) {
      folders.push(temp.map(({name}) => name));
      temp.forEach(({folder}) => getAllSubfolders(folder, folders));
    }
    return folders.flat().map(a => [a]);
  }
  const mainfolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  if (!mainfolder.hasNext()) throw new Error("No folder.");
  const folderNames = getAllSubfolders(mainfolder.next());

  // 2. Create new Spreadsheet and put the retrieved folder names to the Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, folderNames.length, 1).setValues(folderNames);
}
```

- In this modified script, the top row is the folder name of the specific folder. If you don't want to include it, please modify `folders = [foldername]` to `folders = []`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and even optimze the code.

I don't want the subfolders of the folders inside the main folder, so I don't need recursion.

The script is not listing all folders and I'm sure of it, because when I look for some folder in the listing (via LOOK functions and using the filter) I can't find it, but if I search in the drive I find it inside the main folder(not as a subfolder of other folders).

Comment: Now since the time I posted this question I noticed that when I opened some folders looking for a file it would show the folder as empty, but if I searched for the file name it would find it. After I opened the file and closed it, and then went to the folder and opened it the file would be there. Could be a similar behaviour causing the script to not find some folders?

Not sure if relevant, but the main folder is part of a shared drive.

Comment: @GuilhermeAraujo Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it.