# Seek help to list all the files (in following order: Folder, File ID, File Name) in the Main Folder and all Sub Folders in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried various scripts in this forum but couldn't get the desired results. So I seek any help or advice in order to list all the files in the Main Folder and all the Sub Folders under the Main Folder in Google Drive. I am trying to list the files in the following order:

Folder Name, File ID, File Name

Appreciate any help to achieve my objective.

Thanks

I have tired a few scripts in this forum but couldn't get some of them to work and those that worked didn't achieve my objective. Some list the files, some list the folders and others limit no. of subfolders and so on. Those that I couldn't get to work gave "Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end" errors.

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243153/in-google-apps-script-how-would-i-get-all-subfolders-and-all-subsubfolders-and/55248127#55248127

Comment: Please let us know which scripts did not work for you.  Perhaps we can help you to get them to work.

Comment: The one I gave you a link to can take a while to run because it can recurse through your entire drive.  The last time I ran it, it took about 12 minutes.  So if you are not in a paid account you may get a timeout depending upon your drive.

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Appreciate your help. I tried the link you provided but I get the following Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'level')
getFnF1 @ Code.gs:4

Comment: did you include the level global variables as they are shown in the example.  I use them to keep track of the nesting level.

Comment: I guess in that one I left that declaration off but it should be there.

Comment: One of the scripts I tried and would like to get it to work is at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930017/get-folders-and-files-listed-in-google-sheets-from-a-google-drive-folder-using-a

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble in posting and hence, I am going to provide links. 
 Outcome of the script: 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pf2ptnQFe1tv7dd70XYxCT_XQ1Q9Dsj5glC2yn0HG5w/edit?usp=sharing

Link to details (folder structure, outcome and desired outcome): 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iSpyDXKfH2K8ZWFlFkH1oIHEKKii2TOGb0W0cERDSYA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am sorry but I do not follow links to off site resources. In regard to questions about assistance with other scripts I recommend that you ask it as a separate question