# Exceeded maximum execution time error in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-apps

i am trying to run this script in google apps script. It lists all files recursively within a folder along with its size, name, url etc to spreadsheet. There is nothing wrong with the script but the problem is i am running it on a folder which has thousands of files and google script only allows few minutes of maximum runtime so each time just after few mins i get the error saying exceeded maximum execution time in google script.

Is there any workaround for this issue? i am fine even if i have to run this code somewhere outside of google apps script if that's the only way out but then again i have been told its not possible to execute this code outside of google script.

```
function start() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type", "Folder", "Folder Slug"]);
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID');
  var folder = folders.getFolders();
  if (folder.hasNext()) {

    // 1. Retrieve the file list and put to an array.
    // 2. Sort the array by the file size.
    var list = processFolder(folder).sort((a, b) => a[2] < b[2] ? 1 : -1);

    // 3. Put the array to the Spreadsheet.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, list.length, list[0].length).setValues(list);
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox('Folder not found!');
  }

  function processFolder(folder, list = []) {
    while (folder.hasNext()) {
      var f = folder.next();
      var contents = f.getFiles();
      addFilesToSheet(contents, f, list);
      var subFolder = f.getFolders();
      processFolder(subFolder, list);
    }
    return list;
  }

  function addFilesToSheet(files, folder, list) {
    var folderName = folder.getName();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      list.push([
        file.getName(),
        file.getDateCreated(),
        Math.round(10 * file.getSize() / 1073741824) / 10, // Modified from file.getSize() / 1073741824,
        file.getUrl(),
        "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
        file.getDescription() || "",
        file.getMimeType(),
        folderName
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed this problem in the past using the Continous Execution Library by Patrick Martinent:

https://gist.github.com/patt0/8395003

The basic idea is to:

- Set up your function so it can be terminated and resumed without issue
- Set up a time trigger to re-run the function
- Run it until it nears the execution timeout and exit gracefully
- Allow the trigger to restart the function
- Repeat until done, and remove the trigger

Comment: Hello i tried to use that library but unfortunately i couldn't succeed in doing so . Does it needs any changes ? Asking because i can see that its almost 6 years old so some stuff might be very well be depreciated

Comment: If it doesn't work anymore, you can use the same principles to schedule and manage your script

Comment: What error did you get?  It's likely permissions related