# Google Drive API get all subfolders

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I know this is duplicate for this thread - [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But I am intrested if anyone gets similar result as me. I am trying to get all folders from my drive, and I am using PHP. When setting parameters for first API call, part of it looks like this:

```
$parameters['q'] = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";
```

As I understood answers, this should return all folders from my GDrive? Because it doesn't. It returns some sub-sub folders. My pageSize limit is set to maximum value. Has anyone had similar problem?

Comment: are you getting a next page token?

Comment: Oh that was problem excatly, thanks! I just need to recursively call function for getting next page token and calling API. Thanks again!

Comment: I explained solution in a blog post https://faridmovsumov.medium.com/how-to-list-sub-and-shared-folders-by-using-google-drive-api-with-a-php-client-dc45db2c1f75

Answer (score 2):

The [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method has a max page size of 100.  This means that if there is more then 100 rows you will need to get the next page by submitting the quest again supplying the pageToken